# Optimal change with only with two euros coins and five and ten euros bills

Tags: java, change-making-problem

We assume we have unlimited number of coins and bills. My code works fine but the method `optimalDMCA()` has a Cyclomatic Complexity of 8.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

class GoodEnough {
   long how2 = 0;
   long about5 = 0;
   long this10 = 0;
}

class Solved {

  static GoodEnough optimalDMCA(long s) {
    long change = s;
    GoodEnough c = new GoodEnough();
    if (change >=10) {
        if (change % 2 != 0 && change % 5 !=0) {
            return dealWithChangeLike31Euros(change);
        }
        else {
            c.this10 = (long) change / 10;
            change = change % c.this10;
        }
    }
    
    if (change <10 && change >=5) {
        if (change % 2 == 0) {
            c.about5 = 0;
            c.how2 = change/2;
        }
        else {
            change = change - 5;
            c.about5 = 1;
        }
    }
    
    else if (change %2 ==0) {
        c.about5 = 0;
        c.how2 = change/2;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    return c;
  }

  static GoodEnough dealWithChangeLike31Euros(long s) {
    GoodEnough c = new GoodEnough();
    c.this10 = ((long) s / 10) - 1;
    long change = (long) s % (c.this10 * 10);
    if (change > 5) {
        change = change - 5;
        c.about5 = 1;
    }
    if (change % 2 == 0) {
        c.how2 = change / 2;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
    return c;
  }
}
```

Can the implementation of the `dealWithChangeLike31Euros()` method be merged into the other method?

Comment: Contents of this question were edited to remove claimed copyrighted content in a DMCA Takedown Request by CoderPad, Inc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way of making an odd total is with a five euro bill.  There is no point ever having more than 1 five euro bill, as you could replace pairs with a ten euro bill.  So, you should start off checking for the odd total.

```
if (change >= 5  &&  change % 2 == 1) {
    c.about5 = 1;
    change -= 5;
}
```

At this point, you can simply compute the number of ten euro bills, and remaining 2 euro coins.

```
c.this10 = change / 10;
change = change % 10;

c.how2 = change / 2;
```

The only thing you have to watch out for is a total change amount of 1 or 3 euros (or negative), which is not possible to make.  Handle those as a special case.

---

Your `optimalDMCA()` creates a GoodEnough object, and if `dealWithChangeLike31Euros()` methods is called, it creates its own `GoodEnough` object, and the first object is abandoned.  You shouldn't create the object if it isn't going to be used.  Options include passing the change object to the `dealWithChangeLike31Euros()` method, or delaying the creation.

Multiple return points is sometimes a code smell.  `optimalDMCA()` has 3:

- `return dealWithChangeLike31Euros(change);`
- `return null;`
- `return c;`

If you initialized `GoodEnough c = null;`, and only created the `Change` object when needed, you could have just the one `return c;` at the end.  Less returns may reduce the complexity.